# Suitability of an aging nuget package (RazorJS)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nuget, nuget-package, razorengine

There's a NuGet package called RazorJS (http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS) which allows one to use MVC Razor Engine syntax within a .js javascript file.

This package has 7k downloads from nuget.org, but given that I need to use this in a commercial environment should I be concerned that this package was last published four years ago in 2011 and therefore may not to be maintained ?

Comment: same que
and in mvc5 show this error
-->
"Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=2.1.4113.149, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1f722ed313f51831' or one of its dependencies" |

may be because  in mvc5 RazorEngine version is 3.0 and package  not updated(last update 2011)
no review about RazorJS on any site

Comment: Need help guys..about RazorJS

Comment: could you solve this problem?